# À quoi le mot « instance » fait-il référence dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens

Le mot « instance » fait référence à quoi au juste dans la phrase suivante :

> […] À cet effet, les instances relatives à ce projet sont en cours d'exécution avec la prise en compte des remarques et recommandations formulées auparavant, à savoir : […]

C'est dans le cadre d'un projet de construction.

Donc, le mot « instances » veut dire « les intervenants » ? non ? ou bien « les travaux » ? Merci de m'expliquer le sens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Les instances*" fait référence à "*ce qui a été instancié*".
Cela peut vouloir dire "*toute action en cours*", ou "*les développements en cours*", ce genre de choses...

Answer (score 1):

Juridiquement, une instance se définit comme "Ensemble des actes d'une procédure ayant pour objet de saisir une juridiction d'un litige, d'instruire la cause et d'obtenir un jugement." (CNRTL)

En résumé, dans votre phrase, "instances" signifie "les procédures", avec leur lot de plaintes, de réclamations, de recours...

Comment: non, le contexte n'est pas juridique ... mais merci pour la answer :)